# OpenCL: What is the properties argument in the cl::Context constructor for?

Tags: opencl

I'm new to OpenCL, and have followed [this tutorial](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/) to get started. Before creating the `cl::Context`, the tutorial creates a static array of three `cl_context_properties` which it doesn't explain what it is for, but which it sends as the *properties* argument in the `cl::Context` constructor.

However when looking at [the reference page for `cl::Context`](http://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Teaching/Courses/SS2011/HESP/exercises/doc-opencl-cpp-1.0/html/classcl_1_1Context.html#2ccbab6c5d816db3ce06a984d6960c91), there is no explanation of what the *properties* parameter is, but it does say that it "is reserved and must be zero". So why does the tutorial send a non-zero value as that argument? What purpose does it serve? And if you have been able to pass that argument before, how does it come that it is suddenly "reserved", doesn't that make OpenCL non-backward compatible?

The code compiles and runs fine both with and without the parameter there. The only difference is that I get a warning that `cprops` is unused when putting `NULL` there instead of `cprops`.

Also, when I pass `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU | CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU` as the type argument to the `cl::Context` constructor, my application will crash (SIGSEGV) when I later try to create a `cl::Buffer` with the context. Why? Am I not able to specify more than one device type to use simultaneously?

**Update:** By giving `NULL` as the properties argument to the `cl::Context` constructor, the variable `platformList` is suddenly not used to anything OpenCL related anymore. The tutorial seems to use `platformList` to specify the platform for which the `cl::Context` should be created, but now the context is just created like this:

```
cl::Context context(
                CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &err);
```

so I don't get to specify the platform. Shouldn't I get to do that? How does it come I can't do that when the tutorial seemed to be doing that?

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, see the official OpenCL documentation for a description of this parameter: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/. This is the C API, but it is the same as the C++ API.

As to your second question - you may want to check the error result from creating the context to see why it doesn't like the type parameters you specify.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any error when creating the context, that is why the program can continue and create the buffer, otherwise it would have exited. That is also what they do in the tutorial.